# Apache HttpClient UrlEncodedFormEntity limit size

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, tomcat6

I'm using Apache HttpClient to connect with a WS. All works fine but when the application try to send a post with a big size it brokes.

I'm unsing HttpClint like this:

- Doing a post of an XML to a REST WS
- This post is an String, the string is an object mapped as XML.
- I'm using UrlEncodedFormEntity to pass the xml parameter to the url

When the HttpClient send the contetn, from the WS side, the parameter with the XML is empty.
I cheked the when the xml is sent and is ok, I mean the XML is correctly created.

If the size of the xml is smaller, then it works fine.
It's behavor is like if HttpClient has a limit size for post or the UrlEncodedFormEntity does.

any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, the solution was easy: The limitation was in the Tomcat becouse by default the maxPostSize parameter is 2MB (I mean if it is not present at the connector tag in server.xml), so I changed it to 15Mb. I locate the tag connector with protocol HTTP and added the attribute maxPortSize="15728640" for !5Mb and it works ok!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting an XML file, you should not use UrlEncodedFormEntity, you should use FileEntity with the XML file. This way you can avoid the UrlEncodedFormEntity limit.

Comment: Actually I'm creating a String with XML structure but not a File itself, but meaby I can send it as File to avoid this problem. I'm will try that way. Thanks

Comment: If you already have the String, you can use a StringEntity instead of a FileEntity.

Answer (score 0):

`UrlEncodedFormEntity` does not impose **any** limit on the content length, but many HTTP servers actually do, as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' content usually gets buffered in memory on the server side.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. I configured the HTTP Server for no restriction, but anyway, the problem remains.